# soap connector with access token from header

Tags: web-services, soap, loopbackjs

I'm using the loopback-connector-soap and can pass my access token in like this:

```
var ds = loopback.createDataSource('soap',
{
    ...
    ,soapHeaders: ["..."+ token +"..."]
});
```

I'm putting a REST layer on top of this and I got it working.  But 3rd parties will be hitting this API, so what I really need is to allow the third party to pass their token in via the header when they hit the REST route:

```
Authorization: Bearer _token_
```

The app will then place their token in the soap header.  Does loopback's soap-connector allow for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. The loopback token module can be instructed to look for values in headers that you specify: http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#loopback-token

   `app.use(loopback.token({
     cookies: ['foo-auth'],
     headers: ['foo-auth', 'X-Foo-Auth'],
     params: ['foo-auth', 'foo_auth']
   }));`

   I use it myself for other scenarios (need it in my remote methods): https://github.com/ShoppinPal/warehouse/blob/master/server/server.js#L17, but if that doesn't "just work" meaning if that doesn't directly translate into the value also being set into the soap-connector automagically ...
2. Then perhaps you can use a middleware to take the value and set into the loopback context, to be later picked up by your soap connector? Here's some (crude) middleware code of mine: https://github.com/ShoppinPal/warehouse/blob/master/server/server.js#L18-L35
   ... but I wonder where you might write code for the soap-connector to pick that value out of the loopback context? Because right now the instantiation looks to be global and one time so I wonder when you get a chance again to edit it.

Comment: Similar to [remote hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks), loopback aslo exposes [connector hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connector+hooks), which can be used to retrieve the request prior to its execution. This request can then be injected with the relevant access token header and then be allowed to continue with its execution.